# MyLinkedList.java Project Issue

Tags: java, computer-science

I'm so close to completing my project, but I am stuck on one part. I am trying to implement abstract methods from a file called AbstractLinkedList.java in my file MyLinkedList.java.

Here are the two project files:

AbstractLinkedList.java

```
/*
 Models a doubly-linked list with dummy header and tail.
 You should extend this class with your MyLinkedList to complete
 the implementation.
*/
public abstract class AbstractLinkedList<E> {
    protected final Node<E> myFront,
    myBack; // dummy header/tail
    protected int mySize; // # of elements in list

    /* Constructs a new empty list. */
    public AbstractLinkedList() {
        myFront = new Node<E> (null);
        myBack = new Node<E> (null);
        myBack.setPrevious(myFront);
        myFront.setNext(myBack);
        mySize = 0;
    }

    /* Inserts the given element at the given index. */
    public void add(int index, E element) {
        checkIndex(index, size());

        Node<E> curr = getNodeAt(index);

        // create the new node to hold the new element
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<E> (element, curr.getPrevious(), curr);

        (newNode.getNext()).setPrevious(newNode);
        (newNode.getPrevious()).setNext(newNode);

        mySize++;
    }

    /* Appends the given element to the end of this list. Returns true. */
    public void add(E element) {
        add(size(), element);
    }

    /*
    Removes the element of this list at the given index and returns it.
    Throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if index is out of range.
    */
    public void remove(int index) {
        checkIndex(index, size() - 1);

        // get the node to remove, and update the references
        Node<E> nodeToRemove = getNodeAt(index);

        (nodeToRemove.getPrevious()).setNext(nodeToRemove.getNext());
        (nodeToRemove.getNext()).setPrevious(nodeToRemove.getPrevious());

        mySize--;
    }

    /*
    Sets the element of this list at the given index to have the given value.
    Throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if index is out of range.
    */
    public void set(int index, E value) {
        checkIndex(index, size() - 1);
        getNodeAt(index).element = value;
    }

    /* Returns the number of elements in this list. */
    public int size() {
        return mySize;
    }

    /* Returns true if this list contains no elements. */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return mySize == 0;
    }

    /* Removes all elements from this list. */
    public void clear() {
        myFront.setNext(myBack);
        myBack.setPrevious(myFront);
        mySize = 0;
    }

    /*
     Helper method: Throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException
     if 0 <= index <= max is not true.
    */
    private void checkIndex(int index, int max) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if (index < 0 || index > max) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    /*
     Removes the given element from this list, if it is present in the list.
     Returns true if the element was in the list and was removed.
    */
    public abstract boolean remove(E element);

    /* Returns true if this list contains the given element. */
     public abstract boolean contains(E element);
    /*
     Returns the element of this list at the given index.
     Throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if index is out of range.
    */
    public abstract E get(int index);

    /*
     Returns the first index where the given element occurs in this list,
     or -1 if the element is not in this list.
    */
    public abstract int indexOf(E element);

    /*
     Returns the last index where the given element occurs in this list,
     or -1 if the element is not in this list.
    */
    public abstract int lastIndexOf(E element);

    /*
     Helper method: returns the node at the given index.
     -1 returns dummy header, and size() returns the dummy tail.
     Consider the effiency of this method. How can you write it
     minimize the number of comparisons?
    */
    protected abstract Node < E > getNodeAt(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException;

    /*
     Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list
     in the correct order.
    */
    public abstract E[] toArray();

    /*
     Returns a String representation of this list.
    */
    public abstract String toString();

    /* Represents one doubly-linked node in the list. */
    protected class Node<E> {
        private E element;
        /* The data element */
        private Node < E > next;

        /* Reference to the next node in the list */
        private Node<E> prev;
        /* Reference to the previous node in the list */

        /* Constructs a new node to store the given element, with no next node. */
        public Node(E element) {
            this(element, null, null);
        }

        /* Constructs a new node to store the given element and the given next node. */
        public Node(E element, Node<E> prev, Node<E> next) {
            this.element = element;
            this.prev = prev;
            this.next = next;
        }
        /* Accessor methods. */
        public E getElement() {
            return element;
        }

        public Node<E> getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public Node<E> getPrevious() {
            return prev;
        }

        /* Mutator methods.*/
        public void setElement(E el) {
            element = el;
        }

        public void setNext(Node<E> newNext) {
            next = newNext;
        }

        public void setPrevious(Node<E> newPrev) {
            prev = newPrev;
        }

        /* Returns a string representation of this node. */
        public String toString() {
            return "(" + element + ")";
        }
    }

}
```

The file that I have written is MyLinkedList.java (found below).

```
public class MyLinkedList<Object> extends AbstractLinkedList<Object>{

     private Node first, last;
     private int mySize;

      /** Create a default list */
      public MyLinkedList() {
      }


      /** Inserts the given element at the given index. */
      public void add(int index, Object element) {
      checkIndex(index, size());

      Node curr = getNodeAt(index);

      // create the new node to hold the new element
      Node newNode = new Node(element, curr.getPrevious(), curr);

      (newNode.getNext()).setPrevious(newNode);
      (newNode.getPrevious()).setNext(newNode);

      mySize++;
      }

      /** Removes all elements from this list. */
      public void clear() {
      myFront.setNext(myBack);
      myBack.setPrevious(myFront);
      mySize = 0;
      }

    /** Appends the given element to the end of this list. Returns true. */
    public void add(Object element) {
        add(size(), element);
    }

    /**
     Removes the element of this list at the given index and returns it.
     Throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if index is out of range.
    */
    public void remove(int index) {
        checkIndex(index, size() - 1);

        //get the node to remove, and update the references
        Node nodeToRemove = getNodeAt(index);

        (nodeToRemove.getPrevious()).setNext(nodeToRemove.getNext());
        (nodeToRemove.getNext()).setPrevious(nodeToRemove.getPrevious());

        mySize--;
    }

    /*
     Sets the element of this list at the given index to have the given value.
     Throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if index is out of range.
    */
    public void set(int index, Object value) {
        checkIndex(index, size() - 1);  
        getNodeAt(index).element = value;
    }


      /** Returns the number of elements in this list. */
      public int size() {
          return mySize;
      }

      /** Returns true if this list contains no elements. */
      public boolean isEmpty() {
          return mySize == 0;
      }

      /**
      Helper method: Throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException
      if 0 <= index <= max is not true.
      */
      private void checkIndex(int index, int max) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException{
         if (index < 0 || index > max)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
      }

      /** Override toString() to return elements in the list */
      public String toString() {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer("[");

        Node current = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < mySize; i++) {
          result.append(current.element);
          current = current.next;
          if (current != null)
            result.append(", "); // Separate two elements with a comma
          else
            result.append("]"); // Insert the closing ] in the string
        }

        return result.toString();
      }

      /**
      Helper method: returns the node at the given index.
      -1 returns dummy header, and size() returns the dummy tail.
      Consider the effiency of this method. How can you write it
      minimize the number of comparisons?
      */
      @Override
      protected MyLinkedList<Object>.Node getNodeAt(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException{
            if (index == -1){
               return first;
            }
            else if (index == mySize){
                     return last;
            }   
      }

      /** Return true if this list contains the element o */
      public boolean contains(Object o) {
        // Implementation left as an exercise
        return true;
      }

      /** Return the element from this list at the specified index */
      public Object get(int index) {
          // Implementation left as an exercise
          return null;
      }

      /** Returns the index of the first matching element in this list.
       *  Returns -1 if no match. */
      public int indexOf(Object o) {
          // Implementation left as an exercise
          return 0;
      }

      /** Returns the index of the last matching element in this list
       *  Returns -1 if no match. */
      public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
          // Implementation left as an exercise
          return 0;
      }

      private class Node {
        Object element;
        Node next;
        Node prev;

        /** Constructs a new node to store the given element and the given next node. */
        public Node(Object element, Node prev, Node next) {
            this.element = element;
            this.prev = prev;
            this.next = next;
        }

        /** Accessor methods. */
        public Object getElement(){
            return element;
        }

        public Node getNext(){
            return next;
        }

        public Node getPrevious(){
            return prev;
        }

        /** Mutator methods.*/
        public void setElement(Object obj){
            element = obj;
        }

        public void setNext(Node newNext){
            next = newNext;
        }

        public void setPrevious(Node newPrev){
            prev = newPrev;
        }

        /** Returns a string representation of this node. */
        public String toString() {
            return "(" + element + ")";
        }

      }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return null;

    }
}
```

The error that I keep getting is with the following line

```
@Override
protected MyLinkedList<Object>.Node getNodeAt(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException{
    if (index == -1){
        return first;
    }
    else if (index == mySize){
             return last;
          }   
}
```

Eclipse keeps telling me that "The return type is incompatible with AbstractLinkedList.getNodeAt(int)" and I am unable to overcome this obstacle.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nested `Node` class in both of your classes.

The method in `MyLinkedList` is declared to return `MyLinkedList.Node`, but `AbstractLinkedList` requires the return type of `AbstractLinkedList.Node`.

Comment: Ok, how would I go about solving this issue?

Comment: Both Node classes look identical. Remove one and use the other in both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
Node curr = getNodeAt(index);
```

to

```
Node<Object> curr = getNodeAt(index);
```